# "ERROR: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!" randomly happens in my code, how can I solve it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have a project that uses Spring MVC and Hibernate, when i run my application, it runs just fine for most of the time, but sometimes (totally random), it stops with a hibernate error:

I've read in some threads that updating hibernate would solve the problem, but i already tried updating to the latest version with no result

Error message:

```
    ERROR: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
Jan 14, 2019 5:35:48 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener doOnLoad
    INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

It says that the connection is closed on random queries, and when I check them, 1 line before i opened the connection. What can I do to solve these random errors?

Comment: Hope your not using a static database connection object...i need to see your DBUtil.class ?

Comment: This usually occurs if you keep connections in a static or instance field with wrong assumption on how those objects are used (eg if they are shared by multiple requests, one request may have closed a connection that another request was using). However without a [mcve] that is hard to diagnose for sure.